# error when trying to get current working directory: win32app.dll is not ready

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a simple program to print the current working directory using Code 1 from [this site](https://www.codespeedy.com/how-to-get-current-directory-in-cpp/). I am using CINT/ROOT C++ Intepreter 5.18.00.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <limits.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;;
string getCurrentDir() {
    char buff[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName( NULL, buff, MAX_PATH );
    string::size_type position = string( buff ).find_last_of( "\\/" );
    return string( buff ).substr( 0, position);
}
// Driver function
int main() {
    cout << "Current working directory : " << getCurrentDir() << "\n";
}
```

Yet, when I run the program, I get the error

```
error win32api.dll is not ready. Run 'setup.bat' in %CINTSYSDIR%\lib\win32api directory if you use WinNT/95.
```

I am new to C++, so an explanation of how to run this (or not and try something else to resolve the issue) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That sounds like a setup/config issue, so I suggest you add the applicable tags for Windows and VS versions. Did you install the CINT/ROOT binaries, or did you build from sources, and how exactly in either case?

Comment: Did you try running `setup.bat` like the message suggests? [This is a CINT/ROOT configuration issue](https://root.cern.ch/root/roottalk/roottalk98/2258.html).